# How to send http form in Jmeter

Tags: java, webforms, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a question regarding Jmeter.
I need to send api to the server. The problem is that I am not familiar with this sort of type. 
I have done it from UI, but If I sent it from Jmeter it not sent all parameters.
here is the call from the developer tool, and what I have tried via Jmeter.
The problem is that Jmeter not sent the request as the browser sent.provided a PICs from browser (white PIC) and Jmeter (Black), even though I copied the same request. can someone advice?

*** I tried to create the body using parameters and still Jmeter not send all the parameters as in the browser.
it  added content type and encoding I do not know what to add, that it will be exactly as in browser

Body as code from browser, that I want Jmeter to send to server:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectcheck"

-1
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="target_complete_rate"

100
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="active"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="site"

22007
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_day"

16
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_month"

5
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_year"

2019
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="end_day"

17
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="end_month"

5
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="end_year"

2019
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Sample request 1
------WebKitFormBoundaryA3J5COTe7Q4F39--
```

[[image: Call from browser][1 Call from browser]

[[image: Call from browser]][2 Call from browser]

[[image: Header from browser]][3 Header from browser]

[[image: Jmeter body]][4 Jmeter sampler buddy before run]

[[image: Jmeter header]][5 Jmeter header before run]

[[image: Jmeter result - request]][6 Jmeter results request not sent full]

[[image: Jmeter result request header]][7 Jmeter results header]

[[image: Jmeter response from server]][8 Jmeter response invalid Since request is wrong]

[[image: try using parameters]][9 try using parameters]

[[image: Request sent using parameters]][10 request using parameters]

[[image: Response using parameters]][11 response using parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Please compare both the requests to check any dynamic variable or any difference. This might give some more info about your issue. It might be due to correlation.

One thing which I notice is that sessionID variable is same for both the request. Usually, it should be correlated as it is a dynamic parameter.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? the problem is that Jmeter not try to send what I told him to send as is.

Comment: I have not worked on it either. But, I see some difference in parameters that might need correlation. Point1--Add cookie manager,2. In header manager content type boundary value is dynamic and the same is not passed into the body data. In the below link it is shown that both bounday value in the header manager and body should be same.Ref:- https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter

Comment: Sorry still not worked, I am not familiar with this type of API. Do you know what the string after the webkitformatboundries means? I just randomly pic characterless and put them. Moreover In the program I do login get the cookie and stored it, and sent it in the headers

Comment: Since, you have GUI version, can you try recording this with jmeter. Then, perform the correlation and run it.

Comment: Sorry again when I use proxy in the browser, since Jmeter needs to listen to port 8888, the site is not opened, Hence I con not record it. I search In the net and for forms in Jmeter is lack of manuals or any significant information. it is just about json

Comment: Try the same with postman plugin..It may help in recording or Badboy tool that can export recorded steps in jmx.  http://www.badboy.com.au/

Comment: I tried using the parameters section to perform the call, and get response that the values not sent as expected \n issues. just tried to simulate browser (See pics that I added). No place to put webkitformatboundry like in browser call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193466/discussion-between-sunny-teo-and-bastian).